# C# - Extension method

Tags: c#, methods

**I'm drained. Need help what is proper extension method for the string type "words"..... 
words.Text == "blue" produces error**

```
  string userInput = textBox1.Text;
            string[] words = userInput.Split();
           if (words.Text ==" blue ") 
            {
             string color = words[2];
             label1.Text = "The third word is: " + color;
            }
            else 
            {
                label1.Text = "Not enough words.";
            }
```

Comment: `words` is not a `string` type - it is array of `string`

Comment: `words` is a string array, it doesn't have `Text` property. You need to compare with `words[index]` which contains `string`.

Comment: Also, you seem to know that already, as you assign color at a later time...

Comment: What do you want to do ? know if *any* word in the `words`array is the string `blue` ?

Comment: If you `Split` on whitespace, the returned elements do not include the separators, so no word will ever match `" blue "`. An extension method is an extension to a class defined in another class. You just want a method.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get ".Text" on the array of strings, which "words" is.
However you can do something like:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("The {0} word is {1}", i+1, words[i]));
        }
```

However, I am not excatly sure what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

proper retrieving of values from an array:

```
string userInput = textBox1.Text;
string[] words = userInput.Split();

foreach(string word in words)
{
    if(word == "blue")
    {
        string color = word;
        label1.text = "The third word is: " + color;
    }
    else
    {
        label1.Text = "Not enough words.";
    }
}
```

im not sure on what youre trying to do but if i follow it strictly, you could just do this:

```
if (words[2] ==" blue ") 
{
 string color = words[2];
 label1.Text = "The third word is: " + color;
}
else 
{
    label1.Text = "Not enough words.";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to Linq then to find the word blue in the array it might be

```
if (words.Any(x=>string.Equals(x, "blue"))) {
```